# Custom font disappears after some time in interface builder Xcode 6

Tags: ios, fonts, ios8, xcode6, interface-builder

I don't know if someone also has this problem in Xcode 6 but whenever I add the custom font in interface builder and change the text or size of label the font changes to system and the custom font diapers from the list. I have to delete it from my project and add it again to Supporting Files to make it appear again in the list.

Is it only me? or someone has faced this issue?

(I've added the font also in info.plist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting Xcode seems to fix this temporarily at least.

Comment: Still seeing this on Xcode 10.1. Closing the tab with the storyboard/xib and reopening seems to be enough, at least for me.